# self. | NameError: name 'self' is not defined or NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

Tags: python, class, oop, instantiation, self

I quite often come across this object-oriented programming problem in Python, where I always seem to have both of these approaches fail. I have extensive experience with OOP in other languages, but only now using this in Python.

I want to call-upon a declared variable from `__init__(self)`.

**What is/ should be the standard approach?**

---

**Invoking `self.foo`:**

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'value'

    def process():
        print(self.foo)  # !

test = MyClass()
```

Traceback:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

**Invoking `foo`:**

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'value'  # `self.` kept here

    def process():
        print(foo)  # !

test = MyClass()
```

Traceback:

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither - you want:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'value'

    def process(self):
        print(self.foo)  # !

test = MyClass()
test.process()
```

All methods need `self` as an argument.

Comment: To further the explanation; this is because inside of `process()` `self.<var>` needs a local declaration of `self.`, which as you've shown should be passed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `self` argument in every method (when defined in the class) :

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'value'

    def process():
        print(self.foo)  # `self` is not defined,
                         # you need to give it as argument
```

**Corrected code**:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'value'

    def process(self):
        print(self.foo)
```

Answer (score -1):

Someone had posted a comment stating:

```
def process(self)
```

Where `self.` needed to be added to the class method which uses any `self.` var/ obj.